# Templates parameters in generic functions

Tags: c++, templates

I was solving exercise question of Accelerate c++, Which is

> Implement the swap function that we used in §8.2.5/148. Why did we
>   call swap rather than exchange the values of *beg and *end directly?
>   Hint: Try it and see.

The actual function in book is

```
template<class Bi> void reverse(Bi begin, Bi end) {
while (begin != end) {
       --end;
        if (begin != end)
           swap(*begin++, *end);
     } }
```

which i changed into this

```
template<class Bi,class X> 
void reverse(Bi b, Bi e)
{
    X tmp;
    while (b!= e) {
        --e;
        if (b != e)
        {
           tmp=*b;
           *b=*a;
           *a=tmp;
            --b;
        }   
    }
}
```

and it didn't work, gave following error.

> no matching function for call to
>   reverse(std::vector::iterator,std::vector::iterator)'

than i changed into this

```
template<class Bi,class X> 
void reverse(Bi b, Bi e,X c)
{
    X tmp=c;
    while (b!= e) {
        --e;
        if (b != e)
        {
           tmp=*b;
           *b=*a;
           *a=tmp;
            --b;
        }   
    }
}
```

and call above function as

```
reverse(v.begin(),v.end(),0);
```

and it worked, but i still didn't figure out why second one is not working?

Comment: How were you calling `reverse(Bi b, Bi e)`?

Comment: In your second case, how is the compiler supposed to know what template parameter `X` it needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in a newly introduced template parameter `X` which cannot be determined by the compiler because it is not argument-dependent. Thus, callers of the `reverse` have to specify it. They obviously don't, thus compiler rejects the code.

Because the type `X` actually does depend on iterator type passed to the function, you may use `value_type` type from [`iterator_traits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/). However, doing that will require users to use high-level iterators with your `reverse` function, which you don't want to do either.

C++11 has [`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) to solve similar problems. But you probably don't want the code to depend on a brand-new features because many compilers don't support it.

Also, your code is performing unnecessary copies of the object to move it to and from a temporary variable. That may not work for high-level objects without a copy operator (or copy constructor). In C++11, again, there are rvalue references and move semantics. But even then - there could be no default constructor and so your code will break.

In theory, you could use type traits to determine the type of the objects passed to `reverse` and use template specialization to come up with different implementations, but really... `swap` is using function overloading so types can be determined automatically, it supports move semantics of C++11 etc. Using it would have been a problem if it wasn't inlined, for example, and frame was pushed/popped for each element. But it is not the case.

Also, `swap` can be specialized itself. For example, for POD types it can use `XOR` to swap the content of two elements without creating extra copies. Modern compilers do that for you anyway, but just an idea...

So you are better off using `swap` :)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't dedude what is `X` in your code. But there is no need to specify an extra template type for the data type contained in your iterator. `std::iterator` contains a typedef, named `value_type` which serves that exact purpose:

```
template<class Bi> 
void reverse(Bi b, Bi e)
{
    typename Bi::value_type tmp;
    while (b!= e) {
        --e;
        if (b != e)
        {
           tmp=*b;
           *b=*a;
           *a=tmp;
            --b;
        }   
    }
}
```